# TabStyle in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

Is there a replacement for TabStyle in lightning? 
When I move from parent component to child component, I need parent component to be remain highlighted when I am inside the child component.

Comment: I dont think there is any option right now...https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C4EQAU ...possible duplicate https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222285/how-to-add-tabstyle-to-lightning-component

Comment: Thanx for the response @Ayub, Is there a way we can create dynamic tabs for that child component ?... Navigating from parent component to child component.

Comment: Sorry...but i don't understand your requirement exactly ...is parent component reside on same page...? what kind of page it is...community or standard object page?

Comment: @Ayub, I am having a parent component say EMPLOYEE LIST which I bind it to Employee custom tab.. When I click on any employee & navigate to its employee detail page. I need my parent component tab i.e Employee to be remain highlighted...that is what we do with TabStyle in Classic.. I need the same functionality or other way round for this. Thanks in advance